# convert last column of pdfTable as new row

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I want to make last column of pdfTable column as a new row and span it starting from second column to end of the column. last column is too big to put everything on same row.
I am using itexsharp.pdf

```
**column1 column2 column3
          column4........**
```

code:

```
private String WritePDF(DataTable dt)
{
    String fileName = "";  

    //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(m_PDFColumnCount);
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;


    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "date");
    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "time");
    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "result");
    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "fullname");
    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "regarding");
    this.BuildPDFHeader(pdfTable, "datails");

    // add header row

    //Adding DataRow
    for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < dt.Rows.Count; intIndex++)
    {
        dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"] = getplaintext(dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"].ToString());

        pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString());
        pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["time"].ToString());
        pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["result"].ToString());
        pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["fullname"].ToString());
        pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["regarding"].ToString());

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"].ToString()));
        cell.Colspan = 5;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
    }

    String folderPath = "C:\\PDFs\\"; //should be in configfile.

    fileName =  String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",folderPath, dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString(),".pdf" );

    //Exporting to PDF

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate ))
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());               
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }

    return fileName;
}

private void BuildPDFHeader( PdfPTable pdfTable, String strText)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(strText));
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
    pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem like this:

```
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["date"].ToString());
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["time"].ToString());
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["result"].ToString());
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["fullname"].ToString());
pdfTable.AddCell(dt.Rows[intIndex]["regarding"].ToString());
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[intIndex]["details"].ToString()));
cell.Colspan = 6;
pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? It's not clear why this is posted as an answer.

Comment: I found the solution after trying couple of things. thanks.I just want to share with the others.

Comment: OK, I've updated your answer so that it's clear that the code answers your problem.